# Java: How to use Abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I am trying to use an Abstract class `Employee` which has two subclasses, `HourlyEmployee` and `AnnualEmployee`. In the `Employee` class I have an abstract method:

#### Employee Class:

```
public abstract class Employee{
    public abstract double computePay();
}
```

#### HourlyEmployee Class:

```
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee{
    public double computePay(double rate, double hours){
        double monthlySalary;
        monthlySalary = ((rate * hours) * 52) / 12;
        return monthlySalary;
    }
}
```

#### AnnualEmployee Class:

```
public class AnnualEmployee extends Employee{
    public double computePay(double salary){
        double monthlySalary;
        monthlySalary = salary / 12;
        return monthlySalary;
    }
}
```

The error says that neither `HourlyEmployee` nor `AnnualEmployee` is abstract and so cannot override the abstract method `computePay()` in `Employee`.

I don't understand why I cannot provide two different parameters for this method. Since I am unable to do this, how should I go about to solve this?

Comment: Let's assume someone like to handle employee and doesn't care if he currently has `HourlyEmployee` or `AnnualEmployee` or any other implementation. Then that someone likes to calculate the payment for each single employee and the all he knows for sure is that the method looks like `computePay()`. How should implementing the abstract method work, then you change the requirements?

Comment: @Monil  if my post helped you, can you please check it as the answer?

Comment: Is there any way we can add a restriction to the maximum hours FullTImeWroker and HourlyWorker can work? ... LIke we can add a condition at the time of object instantiation but can we add it in the object definition itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement `double computePay()` in class `HourlyEmployee` and `AnnualEmployee`. Must keep the method signature identical with class `Employee`

To improve your code, you can declare your `HourlyEmployee` constructor as

```
public HourlyEmployee(double rate, double hours){
    this.rate = rate;
    this.hours = hours;
    ...
}

public double computePay(){
    //use this.rate and this.hours here...
}
```

You can pass the rate, hours when you instantiate an instance of HourlyEmployee

```
Employee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(21.5, 7.5);
hourlyEmplyee.computePay();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to fully respect the  abstract method signature. The keyword here is method overloading which is one of the pillars of Object Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 1):

This would be something like what you're after I guess

```
public abstract class Employee{
  public abstract double computePay();
}

public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee{

    private double rate;
    private double hours;

    @Override
    public double computePay() {
       return ((rate * hours) * 52) / 12;
    }

    public double getHours() {
       return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(double hours) {
       this.hours = hours;
    }

    public double getRate() {
       return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
      this.rate = rate;
    }
}

public class AnnualEmployee extends Employee {

   private double salary;

   public AnnualEmployee(double salary) {
       this.salary = salary;
   }

   @Override
    public double computePay() {
       return salary / 12;
   }

    public double getSalary() {
       return salary;
   }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
       this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must `@Override` the `computePay()` method in your subclasses, and the signature (i.e. the parameters that the return type) must match that of the `Employee` type. You can then provide additional versions of `computePay()` that use a different signature, but you must at least have a version with no parameters (since that is what you declared as abstract in the `Employee` class). A great tutorial on abstract classes is available at [Cave of Programming](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-video/java-for-complete-beginners-video-part-38-abstract-classes.html).